# Better touch tool disables three finger drag. Why?

Tags: trackpad, ui, bettertouchtool

When both better touch tool and three finger drag are activated, the three finger drag becomes unresponsive sometimes.

The issue is resolved by restarting better touch tool, but it occurs again around a half day after.

I love both better touch tool and three finger drag feature. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue too. Try either of two options that I've found effective for fixing this:

- Avoid to have any BetterTouchTool gestures that involve three fingers.
- Disable Three Finger Drag system-wide in OS X.